# Python - Lambda function invalid syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code, and getting the `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` for `lambda (v, p): v == p`:

```
predictions = tree_model.predict(test_data.map(lambda p: p.features))
labels_and_preds = test_data.map(lambda p: p.label).zip(predictions)

t0 = time()
test_accuracy = labels_and_preds.filter(lambda (v, p): v == p).count() / float(test_data.count())
tt = time() - t0
```

What’s the correct syntax?

Comment: Here is the answer `lambda v_p: v_p[0] == v_p[1]`